# Error when sending parameters to a web service C# through VB6 or ASP Classic

Tags: c#, web-services, dll, vb6

I have an application in ASP Classic which  must send parameters to a web service SOAP that is consumed from a Class Library proyect in C# through a DLL "bridge" using Visual Basic 6.This contains the same methods to request and response.

The schema is the next below:

Web Service SOAP --> DLL (Class Library)C# --> DLL (visual Basic 6) --> Asp Classic App

So what I did was reference the service in the Class Library Project using "Add > Service Reference" and compiled with the respective methods. it creates the **MyServiceProxy.dll** and **MyServiceProxy.dll.config** files. I put them inside a folder on local disk C. Then I register the MyServiceProxy.dll with **Regasm.exe** copying the .dll and .dll.config files into SysWOW64 and System32. I tested it  with a WindowsForm and went well.

Once I registered it generates a **.tlb** file which I use for reference it in my VB6 project, generate **MyServiceVB6.dll** with the reference of .tlb file and register the MyServiceVB6.dll in Component Services.

When the app is running on IIS with an ASP file of testing it sends the next error:

*The default endpoint element that references the contract 'MyServiceProxy.Service' was not found in the ServiceModel client configuration section. The reason may be that no configuration file was found for the application or that no endpoint element corresponding to this contract was found in the client item.*

I tried putting the **dll**, **tlb** and **dll.config** files into the asp classic app and into the VB6 project.

What remains to be done?

I will thank you very much.